# ACR122U NFC card reader connected to Mac, but not to be found in /dev

Tags: macos, nfc, rfid, acr122

I have installed drivers and connected my ACR122U NFC card reader to my Mac, and it works and scans cards (light turns to green and it's making a beeping noise). However, I need to access it from command line, and it's nowhere to be found in `/dev` - How can I find out how to connect?

The System Profiler recognizes it, so does the `pcsctest` command, but when I'm trying to use `proxmark3` it requires the path to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the correct connection point was `/dev/sdt`